# Why does rake assets:precompile in development cause problems but not in my production environement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have upgraded my app on heroku to a cedar stack so that the asset pipeline works. I have followed the instructions given in [heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar) by choosing to compile assets locally.

This has created a directory public/assets. Everything in production works perfectly(css, js, with no problems). Going back to my development environment seems to cause the js to not function properly.

In **environments/production.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

In **environments/development.rb**

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

I have checked the source page and all files get loaded correctly with no duplicate entries. I have read some SO questions about whether to compile assets locally or in production but none of them seem to help. Is there something else that i am missing to restore my development javascript code and is this the correct procedure to follow? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok i seem to have solved it.

**In environments/development.rb change this line**

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

**to this**

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Not sure why this works but from reading the rails guides and quote:

"When debug mode is off, Sprockets concatenates and runs the necessary preprocessors on all files. With debug mode turned off the manifest above would generate instead:"

```
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope this helps someone with similar issues.

Comment: I ended up at this solution too. I saw that **config.assets.debug** was causing the browser to download javascript files that were specified in **"//= require"** directives. However, Rails was ALSO concatenating the javascript files together thanks to the **"//= require"** directives. So, those pieces of javascript on my page were being run twice.