# assets not showing up in development environment

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used `rake assets:clean` while attempting to sort something out with my rails application. This was the first time I did this and I made the poor-practice mistake of trying a command without fully understanding what I am doing. Nonetheless the process reulted in all styling and .js to not get loaded upon site load.

So I then tried `rake assets:precompile`, to no success.

I feel as though there is something I am not entirely understanding about what I have done or how to solve this, although it may be a really simple fix. I did read up on the assets pipeline in the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). Perhaps I missed some important information there (am moderately short of time).

If anyone could shed some light on this issue, and maybe a clean cut explanation (url or whatever) of the information related to my particular issue, (*cue office space bill lumberg voice) that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

`rake assets:clean` [removes compiled assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#assets).

Make sure there are no assets in your `public/assets` folder and then try running `rake assets:precompile`

**Update:**

Turn off debug mode in development:

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development

[Why does rake assets:precompile in development cause problems but not in my production environement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520724/why-does-rake-assetsprecompile-in-development-cause-problems-but-not-in-my-prod)

Comment: I followed these instructions and I have seen no change unfortunately :(

Comment: are there assets in your public folder?

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either. I had tried these methods before. I'm not entirely sure what happened. I've also tried grabbing the same build version of my app from the production server and running it locally. even after doing so, the results were the same.

Comment: No js or css files are loaded? Have you checked the page source?

Comment: wait correction. in the source i am seeing a link to `/assets/application.css` and `/assets/application.js`. the .js file has the standard `//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .` but the .css file has nothing in it.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your local server and clearing your browser cache?

Comment: the .css file is empty it seems

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28842/discussion-between-jordan-dedels-and-jshbrmn)

Comment: Upvote for your time and patience, will keep you updated on this issue. :p